# Issue with Inline Translation

Tags: magento2, frontend, localisation

Can anyone help me with translation I have translated few words inline for example below is entry in database

```
+--------+--------------------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------+--------+------------+
| key_id | string                               | store_id | translate                                | locale | crc_string |
+--------+--------------------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------+--------+------------+
|    188 | You already have an account with us. |        2 | لديك بالفعل حساب معنا.                   | ar_SA  | 1918378789 |
+--------+--------------------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------+--------+------------+
```

But today I checked my checkout page and it is not showing translated word

Comment: Inline translations easily breaks, you should use trasnaltion csv file in your theme, module or app directory of you projects.

Comment: In which table you have checked entry?

Comment: translation table.